# React Context doesn't render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using context and React Router. When I created my context and wrapped my components, nothing rendered. When I check the console, I can see the logged data that I'm fetching (it's coming from useEffect in `AnimeContext`) but the Header and HomePage components don't appear.

I'm attempting to display `topTv`, `topAiring`, and `topUpcoming` on the `HomePage`.

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/dvlprdave/AniPlex)

Context file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react'

const AnimeContext = createContext()

const API = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3"


const AnimeProvider = (props) => {
  const urls = [
    `${API}/top/anime/1/airing`,
    `${API}/top/anime/1/tv`,
    `${API}/top/anime/1/upcoming`,
  ]

  // State for top Anime 
  const [topTv, setTopTv] = useState([])
  const [topAiring, setTopAiring] = useState([])
  const [topUpcoming, setTopUpcoming] = useState([])

  // State for Anime details
  const [animeReq, setAnimeReq] = useState({
    fetching: false,
    anime: []
  })

  // State for Anime search form
  const [dataItems, setDataItems] = useState([])
  const [animeSearched, setAnimeSearched] = useState(false)


  // Fetch top Anime 
  const fetchTopAnime = async () => {
    return Promise.all(
      urls.map(async url => {
        return await fetch(url); // fetch data from urls
      })
    )
      .then((responses) => Promise.all(responses.map(resp => resp.json())) // turn data into JSON
        .then(data => {
          const topTvFiltered = data[0].top.filter(item => item.rank <= 5) // filter out top 6 
          const topAiringFiltered = data[1].top.filter(item => item.rank <= 5)
          const topUpcomingFiltered = data[2].top.filter(item => item.rank <= 5)

          setTopTv(topTvFiltered)
          setTopAiring(topAiringFiltered)
          setTopUpcoming(topUpcomingFiltered)

          console.log(data)
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log("There was an error:" + err))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTopAnime()
  }, [])

  // Fetch Anime details
  const fetchAnimeDetails = async () => {
    setAnimeReq({ fetching: true })

    const response = await fetch(`${API}/${props.match.params.animeId}`)
    const data = await response.json()

    console.log(data);
    setAnimeReq({ fetching: false, anime: data }) // set initial state to hold data from our API call
  }


  // Fetch searched Anime
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const animeQuery = e.target.elements.anime.value
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/search/anime?q=${animeQuery}&page=1`)
    // const response2 = await fetch(`${API}/top/anime/1/movie`)

    const animeData = await response.json()
    // const topAnime = await response2.json()

    setDataItems(animeData.results)
    setAnimeSearched(!animeSearched)

    props.history.push('dashboard')
  }

  const { fetching, anime } = animeReq;

  return (
    <AnimeContext.Provider value={{
      topTv,
      setTopTv,
      topAiring,
      setTopAiring,
      topUpcoming,
      setTopUpcoming,
      dataItems,
      setDataItems,
      animeSearched,
      setAnimeSearched,
      fetching,
      anime,
      fetchTopAnime,
      fetchAnimeDetails,
      handleSubmit
    }}>
      {props.childen}
    </AnimeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { AnimeProvider, AnimeContext }
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from './config/theme';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AnimeProvider } from './store/AnimeContext'

import Header from './Components/Header';
import HomePage from './Components/Home Page/HomePage';
import AnimeDetails from './Components/AnimeDetails';
import AnimeCard from './Components/AnimeCard/AnimeCard'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AnimeProvider>
        <Router>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <AppWrapper>
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
                <Route path='/dashboard' exact component={AnimeCard} />
                <Route path='/:animeId' component={AnimeDetails} />
              </Switch>
            </AppWrapper>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Router>
      </AnimeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1vmin);
  color: white;
        `

export default App;
```

HomePage Component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { TopAnime } from './TopAnime';
import { AnimeContext } from '../../store/AnimeContext'

const HomePage = () => {
  const [topTv, topAiring, topUpcoming,] = useContext(AnimeContext)

  return (
    <AnimeContext.Consumer>
      <HomeWrapper>
        <TopAni>
          {topTv.length > 0 ? <TopAniTitle>Top TV</TopAniTitle> : null}
          {topTv.map((item, index) => (
            <TopAnime
              key={index}
              image={item.image_url}
              title={item.title}
              item={item}
            />
          ))}
        </TopAni>

        <TopAni>
          {topAiring.length > 0 ? <TopAniTitle>Top Airing</TopAniTitle> : null}
          {topAiring.map((item, index) => (
            <TopAnime
              key={index}
              image={item.image_url}
              title={item.title}
              item={item}
            />
          ))}
        </TopAni>

        <TopAni>
          {topUpcoming.length > 0 ? <TopAniTitle>Top Upcoming</TopAniTitle> : null}
          {topUpcoming.map((item, index) => (
            <TopAnime
              key={index}
              image={item.image_url}
              title={item.title}
              item={item}
            />
          ))}
        </TopAni>
      </HomeWrapper>
    </AnimeContext.Consumer>
  );
}

const HomeWrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  padding: 6rem 4.5rem;
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
`

const TopAni = styled.div`
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
`

const TopAniTitle = styled.h2`
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  justify-self: start;
`

export default HomePage
```

If I move my `AnimeProvider` below the `Header`, I am able to view the header like so:

```
 return (
      <Router>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <AppWrapper>
              <Header />
              <Switch>
        <AnimeProvider>
                <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
                <Route path='/dashboard' exact component={AnimeCard} />
                <Route path='/:animeId' component={AnimeDetails} />
      </AnimeProvider>
              </Switch>
            </AppWrapper>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Router>
    );
```

So I'm either missing something crucial or I'm not understanding how Context works and/or React Router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `AnimeProvider` - it should render `{props.children}` not `{props.childen}`

Comment: I can't believe I made such a trivial mistake. I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

`AnimeContext.Consumer` requires a **function** as a child, also if you are using `useContext` then there is no need to wrap your component with `AnimeContext.Consumer` in first place.

Also since your provider pass down an object, then `useContext` would return an object, so you need object destructuring instead of array destructuring.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const { topTv, topAiring, topUpcoming } = useContext(AnimeContext)

  return (
     <HomeWrapper>
       <TopAni>
        {topTv.length > 0 ? <TopAniTitle>Top TV</TopAniTitle> : null}
        {topTv.map((item, index) => (
          <TopAnime
            key={index}
            image={item.image_url}
            title={item.title}
            item={item}
          />
        ))}
      </TopAni>
      ...
      </HomeWrapper>
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes, but my ```HomePage``` is still blank. Nothing is rendering at all.

Comment: Also, have you moved `AnimeProvider ` from inside `Switch`?

Comment: When I move it to the top as the parent, nothing renders. When it's right below the ```Switch```, the only thing that renders is the ```Header```.

Comment: Here's the link to my repo [Repo](https://github.com/dvlprdave/AniPlex)